# How to update JSON value in Oracle by adding over there value from another column?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I would like to update values in JSON in my table in Oracle which look like (same values for about 80 rows):

```
{
    "common": [{
        "code": ["FIRST_CODE"]
    }]
}
```

and make it looks like this:

```
{
    "common": [{
        "code": ["FIRST_CODE"],
        "type": 1
    }]
}
```

I want to get **type** from column **TYPE_ID** from the same table (it contains only 1 and 2 values).
Can you help me please - how can I do it correctly? Because now I've written the following script and it works but it did not change my table:

```
DECLARE
  v_my_json VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_type NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM database.table t
    WHERE MY_JSON LIKE '{
    "common": [{
        "code": ["FIRST_CODE"]
    }]
}'
  )
  LOOP

    SELECT TYPE_ID
    INTO v_type
    FROM database.table
    WHERE ID = rec.ID;

    v_my_json := REPLACE(rec.MY_JSON,
        '{
    "common": [{
        "code": ["FIRST_CODE"]
    }]
}',
        '{
    "common": [{
        "code": ["FIRST_CODE"], 
        "type": ' || v_type || '}]');

    UPDATE database.table
    SET MY_JSON = v_my_json
    WHERE ID = rec.ID;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use string functions to deal with JSON. Use JSON functions instead: [`JSON_TRANSFORM`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/json_transform.html).

```
with sample(json_val, other_col) as (
  select '{
    "common": [{
        "code": ["FIRST_CODE"]
    }, {
    "code": ["ANOTHER_ARRAY_ITEM"]
  }]
}', 1
  from dual
)
select
  json_val,
  json_transform(
    json_val,
    insert '$.common[*].type' = other_col
  ) as new_val
from sample
```

| JSON_VAL | NEW_VAL |
| --- | --- |
| { "common": [{ "code": ["FIRST_CODE"] }, { "code": ["ANOTHER_ARRAY_ITEM"] }] } | {"common":[{"code":["FIRST_CODE"],"type":1},{"code":["ANOTHER_ARRAY_ITEM"],"type":1}]} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8uQUPH2Z)

Comment: thanks! it works
but I do not need additional column, I just want to update current JSON column as I mentioned above

Comment: This is for demonstration purposes, because update is the same: `update ... set json_column = json_transform(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Hello I m not sure this is what you want but I hope it will help.

So first I have inserted the column-attribute "type" into the json_val(in my table i named like this) column which is clob data type in my case also having a check constraint as  check( json_val is json).

```
UPDATE your_table
SET json_val = JSON_MERGEPATCH(
             json_val,
                 JSON_OBJECT('type' IS type)
              );
select * from your_table;
```

Then i have updated the key "type" without any condition but in your case maybe you will nedeed.

```
update your_table
set  json_val= json_mergepatch ( 
  json_val, 
  '{
    "type" : 2
  }')
--  where and you have to put your condition;
```

Hope it helps.